# Custom Delegate present controller in didSelectCell

Tags: swift, delegates, collectionview

In my original app, I had FeedController and FeedCell. My code worked fine to activate AVPlayer when click: didSelectItemAt section in FeedController I have the following:

```
{ 
    let details = videoList[indexPath.row]
    let videoURL = URL(string: details.video_url!)
    var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    if let anURL = videoURL {
        player = AVPlayer(url: anURL)
    }

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

Now I add a new collection view cell between FeedController and FeedCell, when I input the code in my new collection view Cell. I receive "Use of unresolved identifier 'present'".

I know I need to use custom delegate, a cell can't present controller, and I have created delegate protocol, but I don't know the proper way to make it work. I have tried :

func videoSelected(for cell: FirstViewCell) {

```
    let player: AVPlayer? = nil
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

However, when I clicked, the AVPlayer pops up fine, but can't play any video. What should I write under "didSelectItem" and under homeController? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to post more code such as `homeController` & `FeedController` so that you question can be understood better.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Your question still isn't clear to me. Maybe someone else can help. Sorry !